# Pyenv not working to install version of python

Tags: python, pyenv

I am trying to install python 2.7.11 with the following command:
`pyenv install -v 2.7.11`

That is the output:

```
/tmp/python-build.20220622154208.76897 ~
Downloading Python-2.7.11.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.11/Python-2.7.11.tar.xz
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.python.org
error: failed to download Python-2.7.11.tar.xz

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.04 using python-build 20180424)

Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20220622154208.76897.log

Last 10 log lines:
/tmp/python-build.20220622154208.76897 ~
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.python.org
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Wherever you're running this either can't reach the internet or has DNS issues. Can you check if it can find the hostname?

Comment: Note: unless you absolutely positively need this version of python for legacy reasons, you should not be using python 2.7